# Train a custom classifier on Document AI through API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, document-classification, cloud-document-ai

I need to train a custom document classifier though Document AI API, but I couldn't finding anything related in the documentation or code samples. In particular, I was able to define a new custom processor but I don't know how to define my training and test sets.

The code sample closer to what I need is this: [Train a processor version](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/samples/documentai-train-processor-version). It uses the class [documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1beta3.types.TrainProcessorVersionRequest.InputData) to define training and test set, but I don't understand how I can use it to associate a label with my documents on Cloud Storage.

I suspect that this functionality is not available via API. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you linked requires the Document.JSON files in Google Cloud Storage to be labeled already.

There's not a public API to explicitly [label documents](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents), the recommended process is to use the Cloud Console to create the labeled data, then you can use the training API to trigger the training process.