# It's possible create a dataset in document ai processor and import documents via python API?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cloud-document-ai

It's possible, to do the steps in the below guide, using the Python API? I saw some documentation about creating processors and training processors via Python API. But, none about creating the dataset and importing documents in the processor.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/create-dataset

Documentations that I already know:

- Train processors: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/train-processor
- Manipulation of processors: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/samples/documentai-create-processor

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** There are now exposed API methods to [create datasets](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/create-dataset#dataset_operations) and [import documents](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/create-dataset#import_documents_rpc) using the `v1beta3` endpoint.

Similar answer as [Train a custom classifier on Document AI through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482896/train-a-custom-classifier-on-document-ai-through-api)

There's not currently an exposed API method to create datasets, import documents, or label documents. This all must be done through the UI.