# Batch Import and Label Assignment in Google Document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

We are integrating Google's Document AI into our document management system and require an automated solution to import and label PDF documents for a custom classifier processor's dataset.

Is there an existing API feature, CLI tool, or a workaround that allows for the automatic assignment of labels during or after the batch import process into Document AI's dataset?

The goal is to facilitate the training of the classifier without manual intervention for a large volume of documents and labels.

Despite using the v1beta3 API for batch importing (https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors.dataset/importDocuments), there's no functionality to assign labels automatically to the documents; they default to "Unlabeled."

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/76535922/6216983

There's not an API to explicitly label documents, but if you import JSON files from Google Cloud Storage which are in the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) format, they will be read as labeled.

You can use the [`importDocuments()`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors.dataset/importDocuments) method to perform the import.

This guide shows how to do this with pre-labeled data in the console.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-classification-processor#import_pre-labeled_data_to_the_training_and_test_sets

There's also the option of batch labeling in the console if the input documents are separated into folders by classification.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-classification-processor#optional_batch_label_documents_at_import

Comment: Holt, thanks for your response!

We're working with scanned PDFs, split into separate files for page-by-page classification. How can we convert these into JSON in Document format for Google Cloud Storage? Are there disadvantages to using JSON instead of PDFs in the Google Console?

We're currently using batch labeling in the console with documents organized into GCP bucket folders via script. But, with hundreds of folders/labels, manual import is labor-intensive and error-prone.