# How to Train and Test Custom Classifier Processor Of Document AI using Python

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I want to train and test custom document Classifier using Python Code and I found this [train Processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/train-processor#documentai_train_processor_version-python). And I started implementing using this Documentation. But I am getting one error when I call function

```
train_processor_version_sample(497857003374, 'us','a530739de44a7ca6',"Version-1","gs://documentai-bucket-123/pdfs","gs://documentai-bucket-123/test")
```

error:

```
InvalidArgument                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_processor_version_sample(497857003374, 'us','a530739de44a7ca6',"Version-1","gs://documentai-bucket-123/pdfs","gs://documentai-bucket-123/test")

Input In [17], in train_processor_version_sample(project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version_display_name, train_data_uri, test_data_uri)
     52 print(operation.operation.name)
     53 # Wait for operation to complete
---> 54 response = documentai.TrainProcessorVersionResponse(operation.result())
     56 metadata = documentai.TrainProcessorVersionMetadata(operation.metadata)
     58 print(f"New Processor Version:{response.processor_version}")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py:261, in PollingFuture.result(self, timeout, retry, polling)
    256 self._blocking_poll(timeout=timeout, retry=retry, polling=polling)
    258 if self._exception is not None:
    259     # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
    260     # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 261     raise self._exception
    263 return self._result

InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid dataset. See operation metadata for specific errors
```

I have some idea about this. It is because custom document classifier have some training dataset requiements

Training guidelines

Minimum 2 labels required in the schema

Each label exists on 10 training documents

Each label exists on 2 test documents

I don't know how to get labeled dataset url and pass two bucket directory for training and test set  too using python code. Can Anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76483328/6216983) should cover your use case.

> The code sample you linked requires the Document.JSON files in Google Cloud Storage to be labeled already.
>
> There's not a public API to explicitly [label documents](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents), the recommended process is to use the Cloud Console to create the labeled data, then you can use the training API to trigger the training process.